# как мне создать функцию для управления джойстиком двух роботов

Tags: python, pygame

Ребят я пишу код для двухколесных роботов, которые управляюся с джойстиков от x-box. Ниже код для движения робота (с джойстика с индексом 1) вперед,назад,повороты,и повороты на одном колесе. Теперь мне нужно написать тоже самое только для второго робота,который управляется со второго джойстика с индексом 0. Как мне написать функцию,чтобы код был максимально коротким? Ведь разница от первого со вторым только в 4 параметрах value,asix,rc_socket,joy
P.s. я также имею сложности с движением, условие else не работает,ксли я отпускаю аналоги робот все равно медленно едет,хотя должен останавливаться. С другой стороны,если убрать elif: asix=0 or asix=4 pass он работает,но я получаю при движении маленькие значения с осей 0 и 4,что переводит цикл в условие else и робот останавливается,хотя я продолжаю нажимать на правильные оси. Помогите с правильным условием,очень благодарен

```
import socket
import pygame
import time
import pygame.joystick

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

rc_socket = socket.socket()
rc_socket_2 = socket.socket()

try:
    rc_socket.connect(('192.168.1.102', 1234)) # connect to robot
    rc_socket_2.connect(("192.168.1.103",1234))
except socket.error:
    print("could not connect to socket")

joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()
pygame.joystick.init()

joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()
joystick_2 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1)
joystick_2.init()
axes = joystick.get_numaxes()




while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
            joy = event.joy
            axis = event.axis
            value = event.value




            if joy == 1:


                if axis == 1:
                    if abs(value) > 0.2:
                        u1 = u2 = -value
                        print("{}".format(value))

                elif axis == 3:
                    if abs(value) > 0.2:
                        u1 = -value
                        u2 = value

                elif axis == 2:
                    if value > 0:
                        u1 = 0
                        u2 = abs(value)

                elif axis == 5:
                    if value > 0:
                        u1 = abs(value)
                        u2 = 0
                elif axis == 4 or axis == 0:
                    continue


                else:
                    u1 = u2 = 0

                    #print('({},{})\n'.format(u1, u2))
                    print("{} -> sending (0,0), {}-> from axis".format(value,axis))
                    #print('({},{})\n'.format(u1, u2))
                rc_socket.send('({},{})\n'.format(u1, u2).encode())

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    u1 = -1.0
                    u2 = 1.0
                    print("turn left: ({},{})".format(u1, u2))
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    u1 = 1.0
                    u2 = -1.0
                    print("turn right: ({},{})".format(u1, u2))
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    u1 = -1.0
                    u2 = -1.0
                    print("forward: ({},{})".format(u1, u2))
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    u1 = 1.0
                    u2 = 1.0
                    print("forward: ({},{})".format(u1, u2))
                rc_socket_2.send('({},{})\n'.format(u1, u2).encode())
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            u1 = 0
            u2 = 0
            print("key released, resetting: ({},{})".format(u1, u2))
            rc_socket_2.send('({},{})\n'.format(u1, u2).encode())
```

Comment: Не часто тут такое встретишь. Есть подозрение, что на такой вопрос тут не ответят. Тут больше про веб.

Comment: @hedgehogues, у нас целых 66 вопросов с метками [`python` и `pygame`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+pygame), из них только 23 [без ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bpygame%5D+answers%3A0), так что шансы получить ответ есть

Comment: @hedgehogues, "тут больше про веб" тоже очень смелое утверждение.

Answer (score 1):

> Как мне написать функцию,чтобы код был максимально коротким? Ведь
>   разница от первого со вторым только в 4 параметрах
>   value,asix,rc_socket,joy

Напишите **класс**. В конструктор этого класса будете передавать параметры *value,asix,rc_socket,joy*. А методом этого класса будет функция управления джойстиком.

После этого создаёте два экземпляра этого класса, соответствующим образом проинициализированные - для первого джойстика и для второго.  И далее работаете через их функции.

Очень приблизительно:

```
import socket
import pygame
import time
import pygame.joystick


class robot:

     def __init__(self,value,asix,joy,ip,port)
         self.value = value
         self.asix = asix
         self.joy = joy
         self.ip = ip
         self.port = port

         self.rc_socket = socket.socket()
         try:
             self.rc_socket.connect((self.ip, self.port)) # connect to robot
         except socket.error:
             print("could not connect to socket")

     def joystick_init():

        self.joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(joy)
        self.joystick.init()
        self.axes = self.joystick.get_numaxes()

     def.control()
        # Разбираем движение джойстика и выполняем команду
        . . .


def main():                                                                                           

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    rob1 = robot(value,asix, 0,'192.168.1.102', 1234)
    rob2 = robot(value,asix, 1,'192.168.1.103', 1234)

    rob1.joystick_init()
    rob2.joystick_init()

    while True:
        if <Событие от первого джойстика>:
           rob1.control()
        elsif <Событие от второго джойстика>
            rob2.control()
        else:
            # Обрабатываем ошибку                                                                                   


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                            
    main()
```

Comment: Сергей,спасибо за подсказку. Я новичок еще,могли бы вы поподробней обьяснить или оставить какой нибудь пример.просто у меня не было опыта  с классами(

Comment: @ДмитрийТокарев *какой нибудь пример* - добавил в ответ

Comment: Сергей,спасибо большое. Я апрвильно понимаю,что событие joyasixmotion принимает значения только с одной оси и создать условие типа axis 1 and axis 3 у меня не получится? Тем более значение value не привязывается к какой либо оси, а оно есть в принципе

Comment: @ДмитрийТокарев *Я правильно понимаю,что событие joyasixmotion* - здесь я ничего сказать не могу...